# how to show friends list in php and angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, codeigniter, chat

```
if($this->session->userdata('b_id'))
   {
    $b_id = $this->session->userdata('b_id');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('friend');
    $this->db->where('fkbc_id', $b_id);
    $this->db->or_where('fksc_id', $b_id);
    $this->db->where('f_status', 1);
    $sql = $this->db->get();
    $frienddata = $sql->result();
    return $frienddata;
   }
```

The problem is in sender and receiver friend request. In some cases the  logged-in user may have the sender id and sometimes have the receiver id.

I am getting accurate data but unable to show in view page

```
 <p ng-show-if="friend.fkbc_id == $this->session->userdata('b_id')"> 
 {{friend.fksc_id}}  </p>
  <p ng-show-if="friend.fkbc_id != $this->session->userdata('b_id')"> 
 {{friend.fkbc_id}}  </p>
```

I am getting friend list  like:

> 3
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 1

While *1* is the user id itself which is logged-in and *2* and *3* are friends ids. how can it be excluded?

Answer (score 0):

if `$this->session->userdata('b_id')` this give a single id correctly then

```
     <p ng-if="friend.fkbc_id == $this->session->userdata('b_id')"> 
     {{friend.fksc_id}}  </p>
      <p ng-if="friend.fkbc_id != $this->session->userdata('b_id')"> 
     {{friend.fkbc_id}}   </p>
```

this should work . please make sure `$this->session->userdata('b_id')` method here is not returning an object or array .

Comment: ng-if is inside ng-repeat for friend in friends

Comment: check what is returned by $this->session->userdata('b_id') and friend.fkbc_id

Comment: it just shows all friends for this user while in query all friends are returned which we access through friend.

Comment: fkbc_id is that id in friend table which was stored during friend request

Comment: is both of them returning  the value they are supposed to ??

Comment: could you please print both $this->session->userdata('b_id') and friend.fkbc_id for you r input

Comment: in a case when some time the user was sender for friend request and may a chance occur where user was receiver

Comment: in both cases $this->session->userdata('b_id') = 1 while fkbc_id = 2 and 3